# TabGesture on View in Cell in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I want to when I click on image in Collection View, it will cause all to hidden except that image. I have drag an tab gesture into image view, and set an action for it, but it is not called. I don't know why, and how to implement like that.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AAShareBubbles
import SwipeView

class PhotoDetailViewController: UIViewController, AAShareBubblesDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
  @IBOutlet var topView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet var bottomView: UIView!
  var checkTapGestureRecognize = true
  var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    title = "Photo Detail"
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

  }

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if let selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath {
      collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
  }

  // MARK: Collection
  func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("DetailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionDetailViewCell
    cell.photoDetailImageView.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
    cell.photoDetailImageView.alpha = 0

    let millisecondDelay = UInt64(arc4random() % 600) / 1000

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(millisecondDelay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(),({ () -> Void in

      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: ({
        cell.photoDetailImageView.alpha = 1.0
      }))
    }))

    return cell
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    return CGSizeMake(screenSize.width, screenSize.height - topView.frame.height - bottomView.frame.height)
  }

  override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    collectionView.reloadData()
  }


  // MARK: OnBack


  @IBAction func onBackClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
  }

  // MARK: onTabGesture ImageView


  @IBAction func onTabGestureRecognize(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("on tap")
    if checkTapGestureRecognize == true {
      bottomView.hidden = true
      topView.hidden = true
      self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
      let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
      let screenWidth = screenSize.width
      let screenHeight = screenSize.height
      collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
      checkTapGestureRecognize = false
      showAminationOnAdvert()
    }
    else if checkTapGestureRecognize == false {
      bottomView.hidden = false
      topView.hidden = false
      self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
      checkTapGestureRecognize = true
    }
  }

  func showAminationOnAdvert() {
    let transitionAnimation = CATransition();
    transitionAnimation.type = kCAEmitterBehaviorValueOverLife
    transitionAnimation.subtype = kCAEmitterBehaviorValueOverLife
    transitionAnimation.duration = 2.5
    transitionAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transitionAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
    collectionView.layer.addAnimation(transitionAnimation, forKey: "fadeAnimation")

  }


  @IBAction func onShareTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("share")

    let myShare = "I am feeling *** today"

    let shareVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }

  @IBAction func playAutomaticPhotoImages(sender: AnyObject) {
    animateImages(0)
  }

  func animateImages(no: Int) {
    var number: Int = no
    if number == images.count - 1 {
      number = 0
    }
    let name: String = images[number]
    self.collectionView!.alpha = 0.5
    //self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(index: number)) = UIImage(named: name)

    //code to animate bg with delay 2 and after completion it recursively calling animateImage method
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.8, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {() in
      self.collectionView!.alpha = 1.0;
      },
      completion: {(Bool) in
        number++;
        self.animateImages(number);
        print(String(images[number]))
    })
  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.photoDetailImageView.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
cell.photoDetailImageView.alpha = 0
cell.photoDetailImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES
```

Comment: It work, but it still has a mistake, when I swipe into the second image, I can not hidden.

Comment: Ok, you help me with my answer, but the other problem is still there, please help me more.

Comment: if you want to hide all the images except of tap image then you have to create your own login like....build one array in that array store indexpath of images which you want to hide and chek in condition when you are going to show it in collectionview.

Comment: plz make right this answer if it is help to you so it will helpful for others... thank you !!

Comment: I don't want to hide all images like you said. I just want to add gesture to all my image, but it work only my selected image that I choose in previous view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `UserInteractionEnabled` to `true` on the `imageView`

Comment: It work, but it still has a mistake, when I swipe into the second image, I can not hidden.

Comment: I chosen the first image from my previous controller and it perform to this detail controller I post above, and when I swipe into the second image, I can not tap gesture on it, only tap gesture on the first image

Comment: In the detail controller, did you also set `UserInteractionEnabled` to `true` for all the images?

Comment: Did you try what @Bandish Dave suggested in his answer?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple spelling error to me.

On my first inspection, `onTabGestureRecognize:` might need to be `onTapGestureRecognize:`

but when I add a new TapGestureRecognizer to my own project and try to connect it to an image view, the only sent action possibility I see there is to call a selector.  That selector would be the function you want to fire when tapping the image view.

Comment: Yes, but these below answer is not work well. I chosen the first image from my previous controller and it perform to this detail controller I post above, and when I swipe into the second image, I can not tap gesture on it, only tap gesture on the first image.